ERROR: () The provided value for encryptionWithCmk.enforcement were invalid while trying to update azure search service
I am trying to update the network rules of a search service using the following powershell command:az search service update --name "$(azure_search_service)" --resource-group "$(resource_group)" --ip-rules $ipsToBeAdded
but getting the error
"ERROR: () The provided value for encryptionWithCmk.enforcement were invalid.
Parameter name: encryptionWithCmk
Code:
Message: The provided value for encryptionWithCmk.enforcement were invalid.
Parameter name: encryptionWithCmk"
This issue is happening when, we delete the existing search service, and deploy it again using the same powershell command which is "New-AzSearchService -ResourceGroupName "$ResourceGroupName" -Name "$ServiceName" -Sku "$Sku" -Location "$Location" -HostingMode "$HostingMode"" and trying to update the firewall with certain IPs.
Edit: I am trying to deploy this in a pipeline, creation of search service is done in a separate task(using azure powershell) and adding an IP to it is being done in another task(using azure cli).

You do az login and try below command.
az search service update --name "powershell" --resource-group "resourcegrp_name" --ip-rules "49.37.180.224"
Output:

Or
do Connect-AzAccount in PowerShell and execute below script.
$newIpRules = @("49.37.180.224","49.37.180.223")

Set-AzSearchService  -ResourceGroupName "resourcegrp_name" -Name "sample789" -IPRuleList $newIpRules

Note: You need to install minimum Az.Search 0.10.0 version.
Use this command to install.
Install-Module -Name Az.Search -RequiredVersion 0.10.0


Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my question so I edited it now, I will use the commands from either powershell or CLI, will get back and thanks for the suggestion

Using azure powershell worked, I'm not sure why I was getting that error using CLI commands

@SaiSharanya thanks for adding the reason and solution for why it didn't worked earlier

Like the insights provided by JayashankarGS, I have tried deploying using Azure Powershell command, and was successful
    newIpRules = @("49.37.180.224","49.37.180.223")

    Set-AzSearchService  -ResourceGroupName "resourcegrp_name" -Name "sample789" -IPRuleList $newIpRules

But I have also tried with CLI and was successful(check the edit: section lateron), but the only thing I did is made sure that the search service public access is disabled before I tried to add a build agent IP to its networking through another task, so deployed search service with the command just added another parameter to set the public access to disabled.
    New-AzSearchService -ResourceGroupName "$ResourceGroupName" -Name "$ServiceName" -Sku "$Sku" -Location "$Location" -HostingMode "$HostingMode" -PublicNetworkAccess "Disabled"

And then added the IP in another task, using "az search service update" like I have mentioned in the question
edit:
So disabling the public access and adding build agent IP worked in one environment and failed in other(when I tried using CLI), so as of now I was able to add build agent IP using Azure Powershell and not CLI
